# How to connect Enter key to button in Python with Tkinter

Tags: python, button, tkinter, key-bindings

I am developing a hangman program in Python using Tkinter, and I want to bind the enter key to my submit button I created in Tkinter. I have tried different solutions, but I haven't found one that works quite yet.

To download the complete code and a txt file with words used in the program (I haven't packaged it yet) - use [this link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1olwk_bVKcM9fhszDPDbgH-47xwMRRv9e). When starting the code - press *Single-player* and then *Spela* to start the game.

The button labled *Testa* is the one I would like to bind to the enter key.

The code is commented in Swedish, but the *Testa*-button is a part of the function *spel_multiplayer()* and is created with the following code.

```
testa = Button(root, text="Testa",font=("Helvetica neue",12), command=vinstkontroll) # skapar knapp för att testa gissning
testa.pack(fill=X,padx=10) # skapar knapp för att testa gissning
```

Any help is appreciated .

Comment: _" I have tried different solutions, but I haven't found one that works quite yet."_ Which ones have you tried? May as well name them, so we don't waste your time recommending them again.

Comment: Can't find the posts I used as a reference, I haven't worked in this for the past few months. Even if the same solutions are suggested, I might gain som insight into why they didn't work.

Comment: Please don't link to code on another site. Take the time to create a [mcve] and include it in your question.

Comment: Hi @M.Otterman, I have written a solution for you. If you find it useful please upvote it and/or mark it as solution. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3):

Try using this solution as starter for your implementation.

```
import tkinter as tk

tk = tk.Tk()
tk.geometry("100x100")

def func(event):
    print("Ah-ha! You've hit return!")

tk.bind('<Return>', func)

tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hi @M. Otterman, did my solution help you?
If so please upvote it and/or markit as solution. Thanks!